# Null rows not counted in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT User, COUNT(User) as count FROM Tests GROUP by User;
```

This works. However, if some User rows contains null values I get the following:

```
User    count
        0
u1      5
u2      3
u3      9
```

As you can see, the null value rows shows 0 count, however, it's not really zero.

SELECT * FROM Tests WHERE IsNull(User) shows non zero actual value.
This makes me thing that I should change my original query so null User will be counted correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `COUNT(*)` instead:

```
  SELECT User, COUNT(*) AS count 
    FROM Tests 
GROUP BY User;
```

From [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/count-function-HP001032215.aspx):

> **SYNTAX**
>   *Count(expr)*
>
> The Count function does not count
>   records that have Null fields unless
>   expr is the asterisk (`*`) wildcard
>   character . If you use an asterisk,
>   Count calculates the total number of
>   records, including those that contain
>   Null fields. `Count(`*`)` is considerably
>   faster than `Count([Column Name])`.